# How to obfuscate only changes file using gulp in laravel project?

Tags: gulp, obfuscation

Currently i'm trying to create obfuscation script for my Laravel project. I want it obfuscate the script automatically when .JS file is changing.

But the result, it's all obfuscate the .JS file in the folder not only the file that change.

And also, i don't understand why it's running without stopping even when its change only once.

example i only add spaces to my template.js

but its obfuscation without stopping

[image]

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('resources/sass/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename('appblade.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('obfuscate', function() {
  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-:.]/g, '');

  return gulp
    .src(['public/js/**/*.js', '!public/js/**/*.min-*.js']) files
    .pipe(terser({ mangle: true }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: `.min-${timestamp}` })) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('resources/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('public/js/*.js', gulp.series('obfuscate')).on('change', function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'changed') {
      const changedFile = event.path;
      const obfuscatedFile = changedFile.replace('.js', `.min-${timestamp}.js`);

      gulp.src(changedFile)
        .pipe(terser({ mangle: true }))
        .pipe(rename({ basename: path.basename(obfuscatedFile, '.js'), suffix: `.min-${timestamp}` })) 
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('sass', 'obfuscate', 'watch'));
```